# When building an app with a team how do I share data between multiple app instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collaboration

I am building an app, and have a designer that is working with me on styling the app.

I push the app to a private Github repo - but once he gets it setup, he doesn't have all the data.

I know that I can include some data in my `seeds.rb` - but there are some things that don't work in that format (like files that need to be uploaded or added to various records).

What is the best way to use the same dataset across multiple instances of the same app without having to email the `development.sqlite3` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've shared files between designer and developer using a Dropbox account.

Comment: What files do you share? The actual database file? I would love to see how that works.

Comment: We used it to share assets, since our designer didn't do CSS. I was suggesting that you use Dropbox to sync up your sqlite file, since you probably don't want to check it into VCS.

Comment: Yeh I know that's one solution...I don't want to have to share my sqlite file though. That's what I am trying to get away from.